# reactive selection of json property in R for leaflet without shiny

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, geojson, topojson

With the following minimal example in R (Markdown) it's possible to select between two different topojson properties and draw reactively a different leaflet choropleth map according to the selection of the inputPanel.

Is it possible to do this without shiny?

I checked crosstalk and reactR, but I can't find a way to do this without shiny.

````
---
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r, echo=FALSE}
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras)   # devtools::install_github('bhaskarvk/leaflet.extras')

topojson <- readr::read_file('https://rawgit.com/TrantorM/leaflet-choropleth/gh-pages/examples/basic_topo/crimes_by_district.topojson')

inputPanel(
  selectInput("prop", label = "Property:",choices = c('incidents','dist_num'), selected = 'incidents')
)

renderLeaflet({
  property = input$prop
  leaflet() %>% 
  setView(-75.14, 40, zoom = 11) %>%
  addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>% 
  addGeoJSONChoropleth(
    topojson,
    valueProperty =property
  )
})
```
````

Comment: Isn't this what layers are intended for in leaflet?

Comment: @TimSalabim In the posted example the topojson dataset is not reloaded and the geometries of the layer are unchanged. With the `inputPanel` I just change the property base for the choropleth map. The `addGeoJSONChoropleth()` function is just recalculating the fill colors. The example is working but it needs shiny. I would like to do this without shiny.

Comment: I don't think you can get this with plain R. It needs JavaScript or shiny in my opinion, but I might be wrong

Comment: I posted the [shiny app demo here](https://geographica.shinyapps.io/Minimalexample/) to get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

check the shape data eg. at http://rpubs.com/bhaskarvk/topojsonv2. Add two diff choropleths using same data but diff property.

Comment: Thank you for the proposal. It's not quite what I'am looking for. I need to select the feature.properties dynamically because there are up to 20 or even more properties in my geojson file. Imagine you have several environmental measurements in the districts like NO, NO2, CO, CO2, SO2 and others and you want to show the concentration with a choropleth map. Finally I want to calculate the proportion of two gases, which are freely selectable from two input panels.

Comment: I guess an extension of the crosstalk package with an input panel could do the job.

Comment: cross talk is for selecting individual data points, not for selecting feature properties. besides I doubt if cross talk will be able to support GeoJSON data as it is implemented now.

Comment: That's certainly an interesting use case. I will need to think about how best to support it.

Comment: Thank you. May be the reactR package could help. I asked as well [there](https://github.com/timelyportfolio/reactR/issues/1).